# How do I connect to a server using SSMS 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express

﻿I couldn't find any server name in the "Connect to server"... I tired .\SQLSERVER, ., local, localhost... I got an error message "cannot connect to ..."

I installed the trial version of SQL server 2008 R2 Express. Installation was a success. I don't know what I missed.

Should I create a new sql server instance ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the SQL Server **engine**, or just the management studio?

By default, SQL Server Express will install as **`SQLEXPRESS`** named instance - so using `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXRPESS` as the server/instance name *should* connect you to that instance

Comment: These is what I got when I searched for the discovery report Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Setup Discovery Report  
Product - Sql Server 2008 Instance - Blank Instance ID - Blank Feature  - Management Tools - Basic 1033 Express Edition 10.51.2500.0 No

Comment: @Subha: hmm... the "blank feature" seems to indicate you didnt' install any features - e.g. only the Management tools, but no database **engine** itself .... which **file** from the Microsoft site did you use??

Comment: Yeah... I just had the management studio... I now installed the server engine. Thank you...